# Is there a way that can know the `MovieClip` is displayed on the window and not be covered by other `MovieClip` in a game?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way that can know the `MovieClip` is displayed on the window and not be covered by other `MovieClip` in a game ?

The visible attribute is still be true when the `movieClip` was covered by other MovieClip.

And there is a lot `MovieClips` in the game, it is not possible to compared to every MovieClip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `hittest` , it will be used to check whether the moviclip are over another movieclip